# Organizing text snippets for creating different variants of a document (customized for the reader)

Tags: software, tools, business-writing

I'm searching for a tool/strategy to do the following:

- I have a lot of text snippets (informations) which are available for creating a document in different variants.
- The document has a standard structure - so some parts will always be included for all variants, while others are *optional*.

My question is **how to organize those *optional* informations**, to be able to

- have an overview which information is "available"
- see which information was already used in the actual variant of my document
- store tagging information with those text snippets, because some are interesting for special target audiences

If this all sounds weird to you:

The document I want to create is a curriculum vitae with additional information about the working experience I've made. As I have a lot of very diverse experience, I have collected every information to avoid forgetting anything which might be relevant for a job application.

However, this is too much information, so for each job application I only want to add the really relevant information and so I'd like to

- collect all the information snippets separately
- tag them for different target groups, so that I can easily get an overview about the experience relevant to the job, I'm applying to and then can add it to my CV *and* see which information I have already used.

Is there a tool that could help me?
I'm writing my CV etc. with LaTeX and at the beginning I thought I'd be able just to remove certain parts of the text by adding comments, but the source code gets confusing very quickly..

I nearly forgot to mention: I'm working on **MacOS X 10.6**

Comment: This may actually be a better question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), although it is possibly on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You could actually do this in [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php), if you break your jobs into individual Scrivener documents, use the Keywords function to tag each one, and then Compile in various combinations. I haven't used the Compile function a lot, but it's worth experimenting with.

Comment: Two times on one day. Every other person I would have flagged ;)

Comment: I haven't mentioned my favorite program in *months*. I'm behind. :D